# XPath: How to: select all children and grandchildren (regardless of depth) with the given attribute name of the current context?

Tags: xml, xpath, depth

xml:

```
<root0>
    <elem1>
        <elem21 xlink:href="21"/>
        <elem22>
            <elem31 xlink:href="31"/>
            <elem32>
                <elem41 xlink:href="41"/>
            </elem32>
        </elem22>
    </elem1>
</root0>
```

the depth is unknown. How can I select all elements with xlink:href attribute?

I tried the following:

```
*[@xlink:href]
self::*[@xlink:href]
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For just children of grandchildren use

```
descendant-or-self::*[@xlink:href]
```

For all nodes just add // in front of your xpath

```
//*[@xlink:href]
```

Also, your xml sample is not valid but I'm guessing it is just a sample.

Comment: descendant-or-self::*[@xlink:href] is my savior. Thanks cordsen.

Answer (score 0):

`*[@xlink:href]` should work.  It is most likely that you have not defined the `xlink` namespace.

If you post the code, then I can be more precise in my answer.

Comment: I can get the element of the current context which has the given attribute but not the grandchildren elements. e.g. current context:<elem1>   i can get:<elem21> only

Comment: it refers that * is children of the current context only not including the grandchildren.